# What xargs does exactly?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, find

I don't understand exactly what `xargs` does that's why I'm surprised why these 2 return different results:

```
find ~/Downloads -iname *btsync* | ls -al
find ~/Downloads -iname *btsync* | xargs ls -al
```

Why the first one doesn't return what I want? Instead it prints show all the files in the current directory.

Comment: Have you tried `man xargs`? If yes, what you don't understand from there. Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/452222/edit) and explain what is not clear, because our intention is not to copy manual pages and paste them in answers here.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu, why not? I'd like you to explain me what it does.

Comment: With pleasure - I will explain when you will explain what is not clear from the manual page, as I said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all programs take input. The `ls` command can take a directory or a file as an *argument* (e.g. `ls /etc`) but you can't pipe (`|`) to it. So, the first command is the same as doing:

```
$ find ~/Downloads -iname *btsync*
$ ls -al
```

The pipe is ignored because `ls` has no way of reading from the standard input. `xargs`, on the other hand, does something completely different. It reads standard input and then runs the command you give it on each line of the input. From `man xargs`:

> ```
>   This manual page documents the GNU version of xargs.  xargs reads items
>    from  the  standard  input, delimited by blanks (which can be protected
>    with double or single quotes or a backslash) or newlines, and  executes
>    the  command (default is /bin/echo) one or more times with any initial-
>    arguments followed by items read from standard input.  Blank  lines  on
>    the standard input are ignored.
> ```

So, `xargs` will take each result of the `find` command and run `ls` on it which is what you want.